# PC System Status Bios visible through shell?

Tags: power-management, backup, shutdown, bios

I am looking to view some settings that are visible through the bios in the command line. Our system has a built in holdup charge (shows SUSV status in bios) that I would like to poll regularly for a safe shutdown when the caps are discharging on a power loss.

I have dabbled with sensors -detect and only am able to see the CPU temperatures...but the bios shows quite an extensive list of items visible in the PC health section.

The SUSV states the holdup charge % and its status, so:
SUSV    100%/Charged
SUSV    50%/Discharging

This is what I need to read...

Any ideas to make this visible in the shell and/or through C/C++ would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Huh?  Capacitors discharge in milliseconds, not nearly enough time for a clean shutdown.  You need a UPS.

Comment: There are super cap circuits that hold up for 5 seconds. For example, we have a buffer module on our Traco power supply that holds up for 4-5 seconds. This has always been more than enough time to stop all file writes on the system and unmount...

This particular PC has it all built in.

Comment: Sheesh, is this cap the size of a football?  Is this a custom motherboard and bios?

Answer (score 0):

Afternoon, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:
`sudo dmidecode | less`

This should show you BIOS settings although I have no idea if it will show the specifics you require.

Comment: I tried searching the output of the dmidecode but no luck with the parameters I am looking for. I haven't really heard of any bios specific libraries either (Pheonix)...